# Ignore HTML code from a variable in php

Tags: php

I have a variable call `$myVal` in php. Suppose the value of `$myVal` is `<font color="red">My text </font>`, Then now i want to preview only My Text. I want to ignore all HTML code and then echo the `$myVal`. and the output should be without any HTML. I do't have any idea on it. please help

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just strip the HTML tags away from the text you could use:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
<?php strip_tags($input, '<br>'); ?>
```

You basically give it a string including the HTML tags and then tell it to find and remove based upon what you specify, in this case < font > tags.